# How can I get "Time Spent" for specific user and date from JIRA API

Tags: api, jira

there

I get Jason payload by JIAR API URL like this:

https://XXX.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/search?jql=worklogAuthor%20=%20557058:d792badd-7653-XXXX-9ae6-b9f486XXXXX3b%20AND%20worklogDate%20%3E=%202022-01-18%20AND%20worklogDate%20%3C=%202022-01-18

But there is only total time spend for each JIAR card, but not the time spent in my specified date in Jason payload. If I use JIRA timesheet report GUI, there is does time spent for specified date. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure the answer out. I need open a new json payload for each issue, there are detailed logs including historical spent time.